# feed forward neural network fails to classify due to dimensionality of biases

Tags: swift, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I'm making a basic feed forward neural network to solve XOR gate problem.

Standard settings: input layer + hidden layer + output layer, constant learning rate of 0.01 and number of epochs is 500.

Sigmoid activation all the way. Stochastic/Gradient descent for backpropagation.

hidden layer has 2 neurons. The input and output data:

```
input = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
output = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]
```

Now here's the problem: I know bias is a (column) **vector**, and you complete a cycle (forward + back) on a sample data. The predictions after training looks like this:

```
(   0.4954120458511844  )
(   0.5081637529087711  )
(   0.5153967874989785  )
(   0.5653967874989785  )
```

Compared to when I set bias as a **matrix** (number of rows is `input.rows`) and instead train full sample data per cycle, the predictions are:

```
⎛   0.18379659987542804 ⎞
⎜   0.8220424701617579  ⎥
⎜   0.8217815808742437  ⎥
⎝   0.18653256456589742 ⎠
```

which are correct ones.

I can post full code here, but I am certain the problem is from biases I just don't know why?

**EDIT**
As I said in comments, the reason maybe from Backpropagation part (Stochastic Gradient Descent)
Here's the full code (yes its in Swift, don't ask why) and I am using [Surge](https://github.com/mattt/Surge) Matrix library

**ITS LONG THOUGH**:

```swift
import Surge
// XOR TABLE DATA
let inputDataAsArray: [[Double]] = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
let outputDataAsArray: [[Double]] = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]

let inputData: Matrix<Double> = Matrix<Double>(inputDataAsArray)
let outputData: Matrix<Double> = Matrix<Double>(outputDataAsArray)

var inputData_samples : Array<Matrix<Double>> = Array()
var outputData_samples : Array<Matrix<Double>> = Array()

for i in 0..<inputDataAsArray.count{
    inputData_samples.append(Matrix<Double>([inputDataAsArray[i]]))
    outputData_samples.append(Matrix<Double>([outputDataAsArray[i]]))
}

let size = inputData.rows
let neurons = 2 // NUMBER OF NEURONS IN HIDDEN LAYER

var weights0 : Matrix<Double> = random(rows: inputData.columns, columns: neurons)
var biases0 : Matrix<Double> = Matrix<Double>(rows: 1, columns: neurons, repeatedValue: 0.0)

var weights1 : Matrix<Double> = random(rows: neurons, columns: outputData.columns)
var biases1 : Matrix<Double> = Matrix<Double>(rows: 1, columns: outputData.columns, repeatedValue: 0.0)

print("Running...")

let alpha = 0.01
let loops = size * 500

var sampleIndex = 0

for i in 0..<loops{

    // FORWARD PROPAGATION
    // LAYER 1

    sampleIndex = i % size

    let j : Int = .random(in: ClosedRange<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 0, upper: size - 1)))

    let a0 = inputData_samples[j]
    let output = outputData_samples[j]

    let z1: Matrix<Double> = a0 * weights0 + biases0
    let a1: Matrix<Double> = sigmoidMatrix(x: z1)

    // LAYER 2
    let z2 : Matrix<Double> = a1 * weights1 + biases1
    let a2 : Matrix<Double> = sigmoidMatrix(x: z2)

//    let cost = cross_entropy(size: size, a: a2, y: output)

    // BACKPROPAGATION
    // LAYER 2
    var dz2 : Matrix<Double> = subtractMatrix(x: a2, y: output)
    let dw2 : Matrix<Double> = divideMatrix(x: transpose(a1) * dz2 , y: size)
    let db2 : Matrix<Double> = divideMatrix(x: dz2, y: size)

    // LAYER 1

    dz2 = dz2 * transpose(weights1)

    let dz1 : Matrix<Double> = sub(y: 1.0, x: a0)
        * transpose(a0) *  dz2 // multiply(x: part1, y: sub(y: 1.0, x: part2))

    let dw1 : Matrix<Double> = divideMatrix(x: transpose(a0) * dz1 , y: size)
    let db1 : Matrix<Double> = divideMatrix(x: dz1, y: size)

    weights0 = subtractMatrix(x: weights0, y: mul(alpha, x: dw1))
    biases0 = subtractMatrix(x: biases0, y: mul(alpha, x: db1))

    weights1 = subtractMatrix(x: weights1, y: mul(alpha, x: dw2))
    biases1 = subtractMatrix(x: biases1, y: mul(alpha, x: db2))

}
for sample in inputData_samples{
    let z1: Matrix<Double> = sample * weights0 + biases0
    let a1: Matrix<Double> = sigmoidMatrix(x: z1)

    let z2 : Matrix<Double> = a1 * weights1 + biases1
    let a2 : Matrix<Double> = sigmoidMatrix(x: z2)

    print(a2.description)
}
```

Comment: There is a chance that the + - * / operations defined for vectors and matrices are implemented differently, due to the existence of "broadcasting" mechanism. It's easier to pinpoint the exact reason if you could show the full code

Comment: Check the edit. There is no broadcasting in Swift; I have a feeling its because of my implementation of Stochastic Gradient Descent. If I am not wrong, SGD is same as GD, in partial derivatives wise, right? If not, is their any document/source to point out the mathematical difference? Thank you.